# MultiContainer with shared Volume as EmptyDir working however when used shared Volume as hostPath not working

Tags: kubernetes, contains

I have K8s cluster with one master and one worker Node.
Scenario – 1 I am deploying a simple sidecar container within same POD where I have define emptyDir as share volume and it is working fine. The manifest file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
   name: pod-with-sidecar
   namespace: test
spec:
   replicas: 1
   selector:
     matchLabels:
         app: debian-nginx
   template:
      metadata:
        labels:
           app: debian-nginx
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: main-debian
          image: debian
          command: ["/bin/sh"]
          args: ["-c", "while true; do date >> /var/log/index.html; sleep 2;done"]
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/log
            name: shared-log
        - name: sidecar-nginx
          image: nginx
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/index.html
            name: shared-log
        volumes:
         - name: shared-log
           emptyDir: {}
```

Here
In Container – 1 the file is created and the content is available in /car/log/index.html
Similarly in Container – 2 the file is created and the content is available in usr/share/nginx/html/index.html

Scenario – 2 I am deploying same simple sidecar container within same POD where I have define hosPath as share volume and it is not working. The manifest file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: pod-with-sidecar
    namespace: test
spec:
   replicas: 1
   selector:
     matchLabels:
         app: debian
         app: nginx
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
          app: debian
          app: nginx
     spec:
       containers:
       # Main application container
       - name: main-debian
         image: debian
         command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
         args: ["while true; do data >> /var/log/index.html; sleep 2;done"]
         volumeMounts:
         - mountPath: /var/log
           name: shared-vol
       # Sidecar container
       - name: sidecar-nginx
         image: nginx:1.7.9
         ports:
         - containerPort: 80
         volumeMounts:
         - mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html # nginx-specific mount path
           name: shared-vol
       volumes:
       - name: shared-vol
         hostPath:
           path: /mydata
           type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

Here

In Container – 1 the file is created but there is no content available in /car/log/index.html

```
testuser@kmasterl:~$ kubectl exec -it pod-with-sidecar-85f88c9d5d-xjcgh -c main-debian -n test -- /bin/bash 
root@pod-with-sidecar-85f88c9d5d-xjcgh:/# ls -lrt var/log 
total 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec 14 21:28 index.html 
root@pod-with-sidecar-85f88c9d5d-xjcgh:/# cat /var/log/index.html 
root@pod-with-sidecar-85f88c9d5d-xjcgh:/#
```

Similarly in Container – 2 the file is created but there is no content available in usr/share/nginx/html/index.html

```
testuser@kmasterl:~$ kubectl exec -it pod-with-sidecar-85f88c9d5d-xjcgh -c sidecar-nginx -n test -- /bin/bash 
root@pod-with-sidecar-85f88c9d5d-xjcgh:/# ls -lrt /usr/share/nginx/html 
total 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec 14 21:28 index.html 
root@pod-with-sidecar-85f88c9d5d-xjcgh:/# cat usr/share/nginx/html/index.html  
root@pod-with-sidecar-85f88c9d5d-xjcgh:/#
```

Could anyone suggest why it is not working when hostPath is defined as shared volume??

Comment: You should pretty much never use `hostPath` volumes.  In this specific example, if you wind up with two similar Pods deployed on the same node, they'll interfere with each other.  For more routine uses, if a Pod is deleted and recreated on a different node, you'll have misplaced the original data (and actually lost it, if something like the cluster autoscaler deletes the node).

Comment: I wonder if your higher-level use case might be better met by writing a dedicated application to serve this content, though.  I can imagine writing a straightforward application in Flask, Express, Go `net/http`, Phoenix, or another framework that just returned the current time or some other in-memory content to an HTTP request, without needing the complexity of landing a file on disk.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for your explanation. For me when a volume is shared by more than one containers they have their own directory but mapped to volume at POD level. As you said - "In this specific example, if you wind up with two similar Pods deployed on the same node, they'll interfere with each other", it won't because let's say you have deployed two replicas of POD using the above manifests file, then only one POD will be attached to shared volume at one time. Once one POD die other POD will be attached to the shared volume as per my knowledge. You may give more points to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manifest file of the Deployment is correct, there is only a typo in the `command` of the main container it should be `do date` and not `do data`

`args: ["while true; do date >> /var/log/index.html; sleep 2;done"]`

Fix the typo and it will work.

Comment: you are correct. I have changed the 'do data' to 'do date' in my command line and it is working.
Thank you so much. How can I mark that you have answer my question??

Comment: To mark my answer as accepted, please click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: @ Saifeddine Rajhi Thank you I have marked it .. Thank you again for your response..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve correctly, I would use the `emptyDir` approach.

That said, when you use `hostPath` the files or directories created on the underlying hosts are only writable by root. You either need to run your process as root in a privileged Container or modify the file permissions on the host to be able to write to a `hostPath` volume. For more details see: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/